# Pass a form hidden field variable from one function to another

Tags: javascript

The second_scored function is called by an onblur event on the end_date. When a user completes the entry of the end_date, the value of the hidden form elements are modified with data from a query, in addition to other innerHTML elements (i have omitted those).

The other_scored function can be separately called by a user if they want to accept to accept or agree to the data displayed (now in hidden form element). They check the checkbox and data should be copied from the `second_scored()` function to the function `other_scored()`.

The problem is when I click on the checkbox in order to copy from hidden form element nothing is copied and it does not show.

```
function second_scored()
{
// { ... }
    document.getElementById('inspection_number').value = '65888';
    document.getElementById('inspection_date').value = '12/31/2007'; 
    document.getElementById('inspection_score').value = '90';
// { ... }
}

function other_scored()
{
  // { ... }
  if (document.getElementById('inspection_number'))
            {
                document.getElementById('b_inspection_number').value = document.getElementById('inspection_number').value;
            }

}
```

This is the form

```
FROM: <input name="begin_date" type="text" date" size="12" value="#" id="begin_date">
TO: <input name="end_date" type="text" date" size="12" value="#" id="end_date" onblur="second_score();">
<!-->
I agree to this score: <input type="checkbox" name="IagreePI" id="IagreePI" onclick="other_scored();">
<!-->
```

Comment: What's exactly do you want? Whenever value of `#inspection_number` is changed, then assign value of `#inspection_number` to `#b_inspection_number`, is that right?

Comment: The code snippets supplied should work only if they are being executed after the page is loaded. When are you calling `second_scored()`?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working code snippet that reproduces the issue

Comment: Thanks folks. I have modified the question and added a snippet of the code with some explanation. Hope it helps.

Comment: Please add your HTML so we can see a minimally working version.

Comment: I added the HTML but all of it is not showing.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue. You are calling the `onblur` named `second_score`. Your actual function name is `second_scored` Add the **d**. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your question title says

> Pass a form hidden field variable from one function to another

So if you want to use a variable in two function a global variable can be used like,

```
var variable;
function second_scored()
{
    variable=65888;
}

function other_scored()
{
    console.log(variable);
}
```

Set the variable from one function and access it from another one.

But If you really want to set value of hidden fields and access them from another function check this [Jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/zozuya/edit?html,js,output).(I put a saperate button to execute `other_scored()` function since you haven't given your html for that)